# 再帰関数を用いたフィボナッチ数列の計算

Tags: c++

プログラミング初心者です。

```
int f(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return n + f(n-1);
}
```

上記コードにおいて,`f(5)`を求めるとき、アウトプットが15となるのですが、
なぜこのようになるかわかりません。

個人的には　`return 5 + f(4)` となり、`f(4)`は3ですので合計8だと考えたのですが、なぜこのような違いが生じるかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このコードはフィボナッチ数列を計算しません。なぜ `f(5)` が `15` を返すのかは、ひとつずつ順番に考えると分かります。

```
f(0) = 0  (n == 0 なので)
f(1) = 1 + f(0) = 1 + 0  = 1
f(2) = 2 + f(1) = 2 + 1  = 3
f(3) = 3 + f(2) = 3 + 3  = 6
f(4) = 4 + f(3) = 4 + 6  = 10
f(5) = 5 + f(4) = 5 + 10 = 15
```

Comment: 一つ一つ寧にご回答いただきありがとうございます。そもそもの認識が間違っておりました。きちんと復習いたします。